# Show there doesn’t exist a non-constant polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $p(x)$ is prime for all non-negative integers $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Show there doesn’t exist a non-constant polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $p(x)$ is prime for all non-negative integers $n$.

There is a hint: note in particular that $p(0)$, the constant term of $p(x)$, is prime.

Comment: Once you know that the constant $q = p(0)$ is a prime, or perhaps $-q$ is the prime, what happens to the value of the polynomial when $x$ is divisible by $q?$

Comment: Suppose that $p(0)=a\in\Bbb P$. Notice that $p(a)$ is composite iff $p$ is a non-constant polynomial satisfying the constraints in the problem.

Comment: Try $x^2 + x + 5.$ What happens when $x$ is divisible by $5?$